# Define map using foldl instead of foldr and an expr

Tags: haskell

I did it like this – but it is not working:

```
ma f []       = []
ma f (xs)   = foldl (\y ys -> ys++(f y)) [] xs

foldl :: (a -> b -> a) -> a -> [b] -> a
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

Why is there a difference in the function that fold takes. I mean, `(a -> b -> a)` and `(a -> b -> b)`?
Is it possible to define `map` using `foldl`?

I have another question 
I have an expr.

```
map (:)
```

I want to know what it will do. I tried to test it but i only get error.

```
type is map (:) :: [a] -> [[a] -> [a]]
```

I tried to send in a list of `[1,2,3]`

Answer (score 3):

Not if you want it to work for infinite as well as finite lists. `head $ map id (cycle [1])` must return 1.

`foldl`ing over an infinite list diverges (never stops), because `foldl` is recursive. For example,

```
foldl g z [a,b,c] = g (g (g z a) b) c
```

Before `g` gets a chance to ignore its argument, `foldl` must reach the last element of the input list, to construct the first call to `g`. There is no last element in an infinite list.

---

As for your *new* question, here's a GHCi transcript that shows that `map (:)` is a function, and `map (:) [1,2,3]` is a list of functions, and GHCi just doesn't know how to `Show` functions:

```
Prelude> map (:)
<interactive>:1:0:
    No instance for (Show ([a] -> [[a] -> [a]]))

Prelude> :t map (:)
map (:) :: [a] -> [[a] -> [a]]

Prelude> map (:) [1,2,3]
<interactive>:1:0:
    No instance for (Show ([a] -> [a]))

Prelude> :t map (:) [1,2,3]
map (:) [1,2,3] :: (Num a) => [[a] -> [a]]

Prelude> map ($ [4]) $ map (:) [1,2,3]
[[1,4],[2,4],[3,4]]

Prelude> foldr ($) [4] $ map (:) [1,2,3]
[1,2,3,4]
```

Comment: Do u know what map (:)  does?

Comment: `map (:) [1,2,3] == [(1:), (2:), (3:)]`. E.g. `Prelude Control.Applicative> sequence (map (:) [1,2,3]) [4]` ==> `[[1,4],[2,4],[3,4]]`. Also, `foldr ($) [4] (map (:) [1,2,3])` ==> `[1,2,3,4]`.

Comment: BTW perhaps it's better if you ask a completely different new question, as a separate SO-question, in the future. :)

Comment: How did you find it out?
i mean i tried map (:) [1,2,3]) [4] and it gave error 
how did you know that sequance would work?

foldr ($) [4] (map (:) [1,2,3])
($) is the function we apply using fold is it applied like ($) [4] 1:

When do we need map(:)?

Comment: `GHCi> :t map (:) [1,2,3]` ==> `map (:) [1,2,3] :: (Num a) => [[a] -> [a]]`. i.e. it is a list of functions, each of type `[a] -> [a]`. Using `sequence` is a little bit advance, but `foldr ($) [x] [f,g,h] = f $ g $ h $ x` is pretty basic. :)

Answer (score 0):

It becomes more obvious when you swap the type-variable names in one of the functions:

```
foldl :: (b -> a -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
foldr :: (a -> b -> b) -> b -> [a] -> b
```

...because after all, what we need is the result, i.e. `[a] -> b`. Or, more specially, `[a] -> [b]`, so we might as well substitute that

```
foldl :: ([b] -> a -> [b]) -> [b] -> [a] -> [b]
foldr :: (a -> [b] -> [b]) -> [b] -> [a] -> [b]
```

which leaves only one non-list item in each signature, namely the `a`. That's what we can apply `f` to, so, in the case of `foldl` it has to be the **2nd** argument of the lambda:

```
foldl (\ys y -> ys ++ f y)
```

As Xeo remarks, this isn't done yet, because `f y` has type `b`, not `[b]`. I think you can figure out how to fix that yourself...

Comment: This would require that `f :: a -> [b]`, though.

Comment: Do u know what map (:) does?

Answer (score 0):

```
ma f []       = []
ma f (xs)   = foldl (\ys y -> ys++[(f y)]) [] xs
```

Works but why does order of arg to lambda matter.
`ma f (xs)   = foldl (\y ys -> ys++[(f y)]) [] xs` gives error

Comment: arguments order matters because of how `foldl` is defined: `foldl g z [a,b,c] = g (g (g z a) b) c`.